# How to View a TFS Work Item in MS Project in a Visual Studio-like Form

Tags: tfs, ms-project, azure-devops

I'm using MS Project to manage my TFS work items. The standard Summary Task Information window that comes up when double-clicking on a task is slightly inadequate when dealing with TFS work items. It lacks the standard work item view that we're accustomed to within Visual Studio, and that MS has elegantly rendered within visualstudio.com.

[image: MS Project Task Information]

I noticed today that if I set a task field to invalid value, then Work Item Publishing Errors window comes up and there's a nifty little button Edit Work Item... that displays the work item in the standard VS view. Now I'm searching all over Project to figure out how to edit a work item in this view without first having to cause a publishing error. There must be some button I've overlooked in Project that opens a TFS work item up in the VS-like view, isn't there?

[image: MS Project Publishing Error]

[image: Work Item Displayed in MS Project]

Comment: Maybe is too late, but for others facing the same problem, you've to refresh before pushing on TFS server.

Answer (score 0):

It's currently not possible and its also not intended to be used that way. The UI in Ms Project is the native Project UI and is mant to receive the updates to the plan and to layout the items into a new plan.

Managing the contents of the items is all meant to be done from the Web UI. With the new Work Item UI you'll be redirected to the Web whenever you need to edit a work item. Visual Studio, Excel and Project won't show you a native editor window anymore.

You'll be able to directly to the work item editor on the web from the team tab. When connecting to older versions of TFS, this would open the Work Item editor:

[image]